# CATiledLayer gets a incorrect frame & contextCTM.a value (zoomScale)

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, catiledlayer

following WWDC2010 Session 104 I just created a CATiledLayer within a `UIScrollView` for a 10000 x 8078 px image.

I am troubled with the frame & `zoomScale` when the view is first shows at its top level

1. like in session 104 I defined `levelsOfDetail` as 4
2. in my drawRect I call `CGFloat lScale = CGContextGetCTM(lContext).a;`

Strangely at runtime lScale is assigned 0.124907158, not 0.125 as expected.

As well the `rect` passed to `drawRect` has floatpoint values, such as

- rect.origin.x    = 4099.04443
- rect.origin.y    = 6144
- rect.size.width  = 2049.52222
- rect.size.height = 2048

Most irritating for me is that the frame of the `CATiledLayer` shows an origin 0 x 26.93 even though I created the tiledImageView using `initWithFrame` using a 0x0 origin.

Any ideas where I can find the calculation that is responsible for this?

---

**EDIT:**
I found the source for the wierd frame position, which is the ScrollView bounds being incorrectly set at 450 px. that should be 420 px. The layoutSubview routine in the UIScrollView has a center view routine that inadvertently adjusted the y coordinate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a cure to this.

The WWDC 2010 session 104 sample has two `UIScrollView` methods that control the view behaviour.

The first is `configureForImageSize` that I mentioned in my previously posted answer where the zoomscales are set.

Due to the explained float-point difference the imageView-bounds get generated with the decimals as highlighted before (see wx/hx or wy/hy).

To get clean this up I used the override of `layoutSubviews` where I calculate the view frame:

```
- (void) layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGSize lBoundsSize = self.bounds.size;
    CGRect lFrameToCenter = imageView.frame;

    // cure to the decimals problem
    lFrameToCenter.size.width  = roundf(lFrameToCenter.size.width);
    lFrameToCenter.size.height = roundf(lFrameToCenter.size.height);

    if (lFrameToCenter.size.width < lBoundsSize.width)
        lFrameToCenter.origin.x = (lBoundsSize.width - lFrameToCenter.size.width) / 2;
    else
        lFrameToCenter.origin.x = 0;

    if (lFrameToCenter.size.height < lBoundsSize.height)
        lFrameToCenter.origin.y = (lBoundsSize.height - lFrameToCenter.size.height) / 2;
    else
        lFrameToCenter.origin.y = 0;

    imageView.frame = lFrameToCenter;

    if ([imageView isKindOfClass:[tileView class]]) {
        imageView.contentScaleFactor = 1.0;
    }
}
```

Note that I round the frame size before doing anything else with it!

Comment: You just fixed the problem I've been struggling with for hours. :-) I had a CATiledLayer that worked perfectly, but when I tried to change it's position (frame), the scale values suddenly changed from eg. 0.5 to 0.49756. I tried your solution and rounded the width and height of the CATiledLayer, and now it works! Thanks for sharing the solution you found yourself. :-)

Comment: Okay well, it did fix the problem, but it introduced another one. When you zoom well into the UIScrollView, you can see that the size of the CATiledLayer is incorrect in relation to the UIScrollView. You can see it because the right and bottom edges becomes black, as the CATiledLayer does not completely fill the UIScrollView, and then you can see the background color of the UIScrollView. That might be okay in some cases, but unfortunately not in mine. I'll have to try something else, perhaps rounding the scale itself.

Answer (score 0):

I got a little further in my bug analysis.

Having an mImageSize of 10000x8078 and 320x450 Bounds in the `UIScrollView` I used the `configureForImageSize` calculations from the session 104 example as follows:

```
- (void) configureForImageSize:(CGSize)mImageSize  {
    CGSize lBoundsSize = [self bounds].size;

    // set up our content size and min/max zoomscale
    CGFloat lXScale = lBoundsSize.width / mImageSize.width;    // the scale needed to perfectly fit the image width-wise
    CGFloat lYScale = lBoundsSize.height / mImageSize.height;  // the scale needed to perfectly fit the image height-wise

    // debug values
    float wx = mImageSize.width  * lXScale;
    float wy = mImageSize.width  * lYScale;
    float hx = mImageSize.height * lXScale;
    float hy = mImageSize.height * lYScale;

    ...
}
```

The debugger shows the following values:

```
* mImageSize = width 10000 height 8078
* bounds size: width 320 height 450
* lXScale = 0.0396137647
* lYScale = 0.0450000018
* wx = 320
* wy = 363.51001
* hx = 396.137634
* hy = 450.000031
```

so I gather the image size in relation to the bounds leads to a floatpoint calculation difference. When the `CATiledLayer` is generated the bounds are alway floatpoint values.

If that is the cause, how can I get a mathematical way out of this without having to resize the image (ugly thought)???

Comment: Even after rounding the width and height to round numbers, I still get a weird scale of something like 0.249921 causing the app to be unable to find the appropriate tiles. How do I fix this?